# Stack Struct Updating Incorrectly During push Function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, stack

As part of an assignment, I am currently pushing an array of 2 integers to a stack style structure. With each push, it should add the new array of integers to the top of the stack. Instead it adds one, and changes the whole stack to match the new array.

The stack definition

```
    typedef struct Stack
{
    int **items;
    int size;
} Stack;
```

The Push and Print functions

```
void push(Stack* s, int* item)
{
    // check to make sure there is space on the stack
    if(s->size >= CAPACITY)
    {
        // if the stack is full print full stack
        printf("FULL_STACK");
        return;
    }
    // if stack is not full add the ITEM to the top of the stack
    s->items[s->size] = item;
    s->size++;
    printf("the size is: %d \n", s-> size);
}
void print_stack(Stack* s)
{
    int i;
// Iterate through the stack to print the contents of it.
    for(i = 0; i < s->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d; %d; \n",s->items[i][0],s->items[i][1]);
    }
    printf("---------------\n");
}
```

The call for both the methods. locArr is a 2 dimensional array defined in the header.

```
locArr[0] = l->xloc;
locArr[1] = l->yloc;
push(s, locArr);
print_stack(s);
```

The result of running this

```
the size is:
10, 1 ;
10, 1 ;
10, 1 ;
```

where as it should be

```
  the size is:
    10, 1 ;
    10, 2 ;
    11, 2 ;
```

Edit;
The code has been modified to use an array within a structure "l". Unfortunately this is still getting the same response. DKO's theory about entering a pointer and not the value of it makes sense, but I am unsure on the code one would use to retrieve said value.

the modified method.

```
push(s, l->loc);
print_stack(s);
```

}

Thanks, Jake

Comment: how do you allocate memory for you struct Stack?

Comment: Are you allocating different locArr's for each use of push or reusing the same one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a local array (on the stack, perhaps?) is being passed to push() from the code below.

```
locArr[0] = l->xloc;
locArr[1] = l->yloc;
push(s, locArr);
```

But push() is storing a pointer to the local stack in items, not a copy of the local array, so it could be storing the same pointer at each location in the stack's array. So if the same pointer were stored at each location in the stack's items array, then the stack would grow in size but always print out the latest item added in all cases.

To fix, I would malloc each array, initialize it, and pass it as a parameter to push. pop would return the array, and you would free it after its data was used.

```
int* array = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
if (array == NULL) abort();
array[0] = l->xloc;
array[1] = l->yloc;
push(s, array);

array = pop(s);
/* Use array */
free(array);
```

Comment: What would be the code to save a local copy of the items? I cant seem to find an example online :/

Your answer makes sense though, thankyou

Comment: I wrote a suggested fix. Does that make sense?